# socket IO anonymous .on() functions cant use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I'm experiencing an issue with Jquery inside of the anonymous functions called by socketIO's .on function, all the JS on the page is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('bar').fadeOut()             // <---- this will work
    socket.on("foo", function( obj ){
        $('bar').html( obj )       // <---- this will work
        $('bar').show()            // <---- this will work
        $('bar').fadeOut()         // <---- this will NOT work
    })
})
```

It's really confusing to me why some Jquery methods like fadeToggle() and slideDown() wont work inside the anonymous callback but WILL work outside of it and others work in both.

This is the console error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.js:4
hc                          jquery.js:4
ic                          jquery.js:4
kc                          jquery.js:4
g                           jquery.js:4
m.extend.dequeue            jquery.js:3
(anonymous function)        jquery.js:3
m.extend.each               jquery.js:2
m.fn.m.each                 jquery.js:2
m.fn.extend.queue           jquery.js:3
m.fn.extend.animate         jquery.js:4
m.fn.(anonymous function)   jquery.js:4
(anonymous function)        test.js:21 <--- my code section
Emitter.emit                socket.io.js:1295
Socket.onevent              socket.io.js:806
Socket.onpacket             socket.io.js:764
(anonymous function)        socket.io.js:1020
Emitter.emit                socket.io.js:1295
Manager.ondecoded           socket.io.js:352
(anonymous function)        socket.io.js:1020
Emitter.emit                socket.io.js:1295
Decoder.add                 socket.io.js:4935
Manager.ondata              socket.io.js:342
(anonymous function)        socket.io.js:1020
Emitter.emit                socket.io.js:1295
Socket.onPacket             socket.io.js:1731
(anonymous function)        socket.io.js:1548
Emitter.emit                socket.io.js:1295
Transport.onPacket          socket.io.js:2108
Transport.onData            socket.io.js:2100
ws.onmessage
```

My question is what is happening? Is this some kind of scope issue? Where does that issue reside (my code, my use, Jquery )?

UPDATE: Vikram Deshmukh suggested to  put a reference to the jquery I want to run in a local, which half works. Here's the code and effect.

```
var obj = $('bar').fadeOut()       // <-- works, fades out early
var selected = $('bar')
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('bar').fadeOut()             // <---- same
    socket.on("foo", function( obj ){
        $('bar').html( obj )       // <---- same
        $('bar').show()            // <---- same
        $('bar').fadeOut()         // <---- same
        obj                    // <--- this will work here
        selected.fadeOut()     // <--- this will FAIL, same error
    })
})
```

This could be great answer if...

1. I accept it's a scope mismatch, seems like it, I'd like to know how though? I've done this before.
2. Not as important but how does one do this   **var obj = $('bar').fadeOut()**
   without running the code?

Comment: .fadeOut()  is working outside of the anon function?? right? did you double check?

Comment: are you positive that the on() is firing? try a console log. i suspect only the first fadeOut (the ready one) is firing. i could be wrong. also, why are you using "bar" tags instead of a html tag?

Comment: yes, if i have an alert("asdasdasd") it will fire

Comment: and @Scott Selby, yea, I found that really weird

Comment: try it with its parent

Comment: It's anything I could call it on $("*") and it will fail. Same error.

Comment: You've taken the reference in a global variable that may not be accessible in a function within a function. You need to declare the variable `selected` within the `document.ready` method (refer sample code in my solution). Doing so will ensure that it is accessible within the `on.foo` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you remember the reference to the object in a local variable? This will take care of any issues arising due to scope mismatch.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bar = $('bar');
    bar.fadeOut()             
    socket.on("foo", function( obj ){
        bar.html( obj )       
        bar.show()            
        bar.fadeOut()         
    })
})
```

Comment: do you mean something like var doit = $("asd").fadeOut() and call that in the socket.on(...)

Comment: almost solves the issue and answers my question, I updated my original post.